# Ambiguous field name between an alias and a field in the select list with name

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a SQL query to link many tables using the word "using" and one of the tables occurs in each element, error:

> Ambiguous field name between an alias and a field in the select list with the name. ID_DEPARTMENT

how to change the query correctly? Request link: https://pastebin.com/t2rqMAut

```
select id_teacher, fio, post, teachersanddepartments.id_department, 
       name_of_department, id_subject, name_of_subject, specific, 
       subjects.id_department, name_of_department,
       id_classroom, number_of_classroom, specific, 
       classrooms.id_department, name_of_department, id_group, 
       name_of_group, groups.id_department, name_of_department,
       specifics, daytime, pair, NUMERATOR_DENOMINATOR, keyy, typekey
from ((((classes join teachers using(id_teacher) join teachersanddepartments 

using(id_teacher) join departments using(id_department))
join subjects using (id_subject) join departments using(id_department))
join classrooms using(id_classroom) join departments using(id_department))
join groups using (id_group) join departments using(id_department))
```

this is a query to initialize the schedule items, each item belongs to its own Department, so i need to add the departments table every time. 
Database schema: [Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKsGr.png)

I attach the database file [example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xMdj7TurtoClrpt_BB6LMj1RCyf2A2-W)
current version of Firebird: 2.5.7

Comment: You probably need to specify which table's `id_department` field you are using (as you have with `teachersanddepartments.id_department` at the top) in all of the other places you reference the field.

Comment: Could you please reduce your query to the minimum necessary to reproduce this, and provide the necessary DDL. Check [mcve] for information. I guess this is a result of Firebird not knowing which table to choose for the join. You may need to explicitly specify `on <table1>.id_department = <table2>.id_department` instead of just `using(id_department)`

Comment: And I tested that theory, and with a simple query that doesn't seem to be the case, so it would be really helpful to have an easy reproducible example to experiment on.

Comment: I edited my question, added some information. I tried to make the proposed options, it does not work, the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it, i add alias to all departments tables. Thanks everybody! You help me =)

```
select id_teacher, fio, post, teachersanddepartments.id_department , d1.name_of_department, id_subject, name_of_subject, subjects.specific, subjects.id_department, d2.name_of_department,
    id_classroom, number_of_classroom, classrooms.specific, classrooms.id_department, d3.name_of_department, id_group, name_of_group, groups.id_department, d4.name_of_department,
    specifics, daytime, pair, NUMERATOR_DENOMINATOR, keyy, typekey
    from ((((classes join teachers using(id_teacher) join teachersanddepartments using(id_teacher) join departments d1 on d1.id_department = teachersanddepartments.id_department)
    join subjects using (id_subject) join departments d2 on d2.id_department = subjects.id_department)
    join classrooms using(id_classroom) join departments d3 on d3.id_department = classrooms.id_department)
    join groups using (id_group) join departments d4 on d4.id_department = groups.id_department)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you repeatedly join the table `departments` without aliasing it. When you then reference `departments.id_department` in the select list, Firebird doesn't know which of the four instances of `departments` it needs to use.

You either need to change your query so you only reference `departments` once, or if for some reason you need it (I don't think you do, as demonstrated by the answer of scaisEdge), you need to explicitly alias each occurrence of `departments` and then qualify the column name with the right alias.

Comment: Argh, this can't be the problem, because `departments.id_department` isn't even in the select list. I'll leave it here for now until I can find out exactly where things are going wrong, because I suspect it will be a hint to where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ambiguous columns, the first occurred if for the nested join from `departments`, `teachersanddepartments` and `teachers`.

But each time you use the same column name coming for different tables. You have the same problems, so I have disambiguated the columns for `teachersanddepartments`, `subjects`, `classrooms`, `groups`:

```
select id_teacher
      , fio
      , post
      , teachersanddepartments.id_department
      , teachersanddepartments.name_of_department
      , id_subject
      , name_of_subject
      , specific
      , subjects.id_department
      , subjects.name_of_department
      , id_classroom
      , number_of_classroom
      , classrooms.specific
      , classrooms.id_department
      , classrooms.name_of_department
      , id_group
      , name_of_group
      , groups.id_department
      , groups.name_of_department
      , groups.specifics
      , daytime
      , pair
      , NUMERATOR_DENOMINATOR
      , keyy
      , typekey
from (
      (
        (
          ( classes join teachers using(id_teacher) 
            join teachersanddepartments using(id_teacher) 
            join departments ON departments.id_department = teachersanddepartments.id_department
          )
            join subjects using (id_subject) join departments using(id_department)
        )
    join classrooms using(id_classroom) join departments using(id_department)
      )
    join groups using (id_group) join departments using(id_department)
)
```

And due to the fact you are using `INNER JOIN` the `()` for the JOIN seems unnecessary and redundant too.

With nested joins, you join the table `departments` 3 times; without  `()`  nested  join you need one join only:

```
select id_teacher
      , fio
      , post
      , teachersanddepartments.id_department
      , teachersanddepartments.name_of_department
      , id_subject
      , name_of_subject
      , specific
      , subjects.id_department
      , subjects.name_of_department
      , id_classroom
      , number_of_classroom
      , classrooms.specific
      , classrooms.id_department
      , classrooms.name_of_department
      , id_group
      , name_of_group
      , groups.id_department
      , groups.name_of_department
      , groups.specifics
      , daytime
      , pair
      , NUMERATOR_DENOMINATOR
      , keyy
      , typekey
from classes join teachers using(id_teacher) 
join teachersanddepartments using(id_teacher) 
join departments ON departments.id_department = teachersanddepartments.id_department
join subjects using (id_subject) 

join classrooms using(id_classroom) 

join groups using (id_group)
```

and as suggested  by Mark Rotteveel in a proper answer this could  be the reason for your error

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that is the problem, because I tried multiple joins between tables with the same column names and Firebird didn't give this error.

Comment: i have  looked  at the query and in the nested  part for join that involve  teachers,  teachersanddepartments and departement the use of using(department_id) refer to ambiguos columns .because  department_id  is present in all the 3 tables

Comment: Sure, but I have tried multiple joins between tables with the same column with `using`, and Firebird didn't give me this error. The error is specifically about the select list, which makes me wonder if the error shown in the question may not actual refer to a different column instead (as all id_department columns in the select list are qualified).

Comment: Anyway the ambiguity for department_id is only the first encuntered in where clause parsing.. in the query thereare  others  ambiguity .. i think the OP can give us some info ..  for the ambiguity  situation ..

Comment: I think your latest edit shows the actual problem. It looks like it is indeed the repeated joins to the same table. I had missed that in the density of the code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel   could be  ..anyway  .. in  this way the asnwer shoulfd suggest at the OP the right  road ..  
at least I hope

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  thanks again for editing and support  .. seems that is question is interesting just for me and you  ..

Comment: You're welcome; I actively monitor the Firebird tag, which might explain it :)

Comment: do you have some more thinks about it? i don`t know how it do =(

Comment: @AntonZybekov   you comment is not clear  to   .. please explain better  .. you have error ??

Comment: Yes, there is still a mistake.

Comment: have you tried  using the second  query i have in answer ?